# Create config object with array containing key-value pairs

Tags: 8, forms, hooks, configuration

We have a custom module, `mymodule`, that we want to use to create a config object for so that it can contain an array of `key-value` pairs. We need to be able to click button `Add More` on the form that will add more `key` and `value` fields that will be mapped together.

**How can we create a form that would not only display existing `key-value` pairs, but also provide option to add more?**

Goals:

1. On the admin Form, `MyModuleForm` be able to see existing `key-value` pairs.
2. Add more `key-value` pairs.
3. `Key` and `value` are text fields.
4. Use the `config_object` within the `mymodule.module` file and fetch all the `key-value` pairs.

Below is what we tried, but got stuck on how to add the `Add more` functionality and how to properly store `customKey` and `customValue` into an `array`.

**MyModuleForm.php**

```
class MyModuleForm extends ConfigFormbase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return [
      'mymodule.settings'
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'mymodule_settings';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('mymodule.settings');
    $form['customKey'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('Key value for array.'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => $config->get('customKey'),
      '#maxlength' => 255,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];
    $form['customValue'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('value for array.'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => $config->get('customValue'),
      '#maxlength' => 255,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Retrieve the configuration
    $this->configFactory->getEditable('mymodule.settings')
      ->set('customKey', $form_state->getValue('customKey'))
      ->set('customValue', $form_state->getValue('customValue'))
      ->save();

    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add an add more button you'll need to create a callback function that will increase the number of fields necessary and rebuild that part of the form based on that information. You can make a new config variable based on some sort of index as you do a loop through all the necessary fields.

I haven't tested this so the syntax might be off but here's the basic idea in an example I wrote.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        if (empty($number_of_member_fields)) {
            $number_of_member_fields = $form_state->set('number_of_member_fields', 1);
        }
        $forms['members_fieldset'] = [
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            '#title' => t('Member types'),
            '#attributes' => [
                'id' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper'
            ],
        ];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_member_fields; $i++) {
            $form['members_fieldset']['memberType'.$i] = [
                '#type'          => 'textfield',
                '#title'         => t('Name'),
                '#default_value' => $config->get('memberType'.$i),
            ];
        }
        $form['members_fieldset']['actions']['add_name'] = [
            '#type'     => 'submit',
            '#value'    => t('Add one more'),
            '#submit'   => array('::addOne'),
            '#ajax'     => [
                'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
                'wrapper'  => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
            ],
        ];
    }
    public function addmoreCallback(array&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        return $form['members_fieldset'];
    }
    public function addOne(array&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $number_of_member_fields = $form_state->get('number_of_member_fields');
        $number_of_member_fields++;
        $form_state->set('number_of_member_fields', $number_of_member_fields);
        $form_state->setRebuild();
    }
```